# Django admin site change_list view customization

Tags: python, django, django-admin, overriding, django-modeladmin

I have a `ModelAdmin` subclass for my `gradeScalesSettings` model:

```
@admin.register(gradeScalesSetting)
class gradeScalesSettingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('configuration_select', 'NumberOfGrades', 'Rounding','Precision', 'Status',)
    change_list_template = 'admin/Homepage/view.html'
```

[image]

## Actual result

After I click **Grade Scale Settings**:

[image]

How to connect it to my views.py?
This is what I want to code in my views.py:

```
def gradescales(request):
    gradeScalesSettings = gradeScalesSetting.objects.all()
    configurations = configuration.objects.all()
    rounding = gradeScalesSetting.objects.all().values_list('Rounding', flat=True).distinct()
    print(rounding)
    return render(request, 'Homepage/gradescale.html', {"rounding": rounding,"gradeScalesSetting":gradeScalesSettings,"configurations":configurations})
```

When I tried this:

```
@admin.register(gradeScalesSetting)
class gradeScalesSettingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def new_NumberOfGrades(self, obj):
        if obj.NumberOfGrades == 'Grade Scale Settings':
            return '<a href="view.html" </a>'  # this url will redirect to your
```

In my `ModelAdmin` subclass:

```
list_display = ('configuration_select', 'new_NumberOfGrades', 'Rounding','Precision', 'Status',)
```

[image]

Is there any way to connect it to my views.py?

## Expected result

This is what I want to show in my view.html:

[image]

That is why I want to connect it to my views.py.

Comment: What's the difference between view.html and gradescale.html?

Answer (score 6):

Override [`ModelAdmin.changelist_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view) to set `extra_context`.

```py
@admin.register(gradeScalesSetting)
class gradeScalesSettingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('configuration_select', 'NumberOfGrades', 'Rounding','Precision', 'Status',)
    change_list_template = 'admin/Homepage/view.html'

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}

        gradeScalesSettings = gradeScalesSetting.objects.all()
        configurations = configuration.objects.all()
        rounding = gradeScalesSetting.objects.all().values_list('Rounding', flat=True).distinct()

        extra_context.update({
            "rounding": rounding,
            "gradeScalesSetting": gradeScalesSettings,
            "configurations": configurations,
        })
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Comment: After that, where exactly should I implement the new context variables in the corresponding template?

Comment: I just wanted to know wheter this alone does the trick, or customizing change_list.html is also necessary in order to effectivelly render the customizations. This looks like my problem almost exactly.

Comment: Customizing change_list.html (as OP does with admin/Homepage/view.html) is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter routing for ModelAdmin by overriding `get_urls`:

```
class gradeScalesSettingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        pat = [i for i in urls if str(i.name).endswith('changelist')][0]  # Find needed path object to replace
        index = urls.index(pat)
        urls[index] = path(pat.pattern._route, gradescales)
        return urls
```

This way you can have full control of a view used for your admin page and  even add additional pages (more than only changelist and edit views) as you want.

If you do not need additional default views like object edit page, you can simplify code above by replacing original urls instead of searching one needed and patching:

```
class gradeScalesSettingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = [
            path('', gradescales)
        ]
        return urls
```